# Python does not identify the academic version of CPLEX

Tags: cplex, python

Python does not identify the academic version of CPLEX.

I am using Linux, Ubuntu. I have Python 3.6. I installed CPLEX studio 12.9 (academic version installed via the file `cplex_studio129.linux-x86-64.bin` that I downloaded from `ibm.biz/CPLEXonAI`) installed at `\opt` directory.

I also installed the file `setup.py` that is available in `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_linux`, using the terminal.

With all those, when I run my code in PyCharm, or in Terminal, I get: `CPLEX Error  1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded. Purchase at https://ibm.co/2s0wqSa.`

I found some similar questions, with helps suggesting to do correct the `PYTHONPATH`, but I could not understand what to do actually.

Comment: There are some related questions about that. For instance, Would you see this [link](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/881/python-api-and-cplex)?

Comment: Try removing the Community Edition from your computer.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you very much for the great help. It was as simple as that! I post what I did for further reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all for the great suggestions. The thing that should be done is to install CPLEX `setup.py` in the site-packages of the python. But it is not enough. Actually, what worked was the suggestion to remove the community version first (as MarkL.Stone suggested).

So, what I suggest for further reference is to do something like:

---

1- Remove your CPLEX community version.

It can be in a folder like the following:
`/home/<<your-computer-name>>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cplex/`

For this, you can open terminal and run:

`rm -r /home/<<your-computer-name>>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cplex/`

---

2- Install the CPLEX `setup.py` file.

For this, go to the folder that CPLEX is installed, and go to the following subfolder: `opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/python` (`opt` is where my CPLEX is installed). Then open the terminal and run:

`sudo python setup.py install --home home/<<your-computer-name>>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cplex`

---

Note that you should adjust the part `<<your-computer-name>>` in the commands in both steps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `home` option, `python setup.py install --home /path/to/python`, is really important when it comes to the virtual environment.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this problem in the past with `CPLEX Error 1016`, though in Windows, and this is how I resolved it (assuming you have the correct installation of CPLEX on your machine and the appropriate python packages):

- From the command prompt, go to the directory where CPLEX is installed (e.g. "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio129\python")
- Run `python setup.py install`
- Restart your system!

After doing these steps, when I navigate to the system path, I could see the path for CPLEX. You can check that on your machine too by doing the following (again, this is for windows but hopefully the idea is the same):

- Go to Control panel > Edit the system environment variables > Advanced > Environment Variables...>
- In the "User variables for *your_name*", you'll see "Path". Make sure you see the path for the cplex.exe and python version you have installed the `setup.py` for. 
  For example:

  "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio129\cplex\python\3.6\x64_win64" and

  "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio129\cplex\bin\x64_win64\cplex.exe"